# java stream - flatmap with method reference

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to java and to stream so my question is why does this work:

This method is in my `Tree` class:

```
public Stream<Tree> flattened() {
    return Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(this),
            children.stream().flatMap(Tree::flattened));
}
```

flatMap wants a function with t as param and flattened method doesnt have input parameters at all

whats happening here?

Comment: @Jeremy you are looking at it

Comment: @Jeremy That *is* the source for `Tree::flattened`.

Comment: the source is the same method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is indeed a hidden parameter in your function call.  Because `flattened` is a non-static method, there is an implicit parameter in your function, which is known as `this`.

Basically, you are calling `flattened` on each object in your stream, with the said element being your parameter.

EDIT (for clarification): `Tree::flattened` can mean one of two things.  It could mean:

```
tree -> Tree.flattened(tree) //flattened is a static method, which yours is not
```

or it could also mean:

```
tree -> tree.flattened() //flattened is an instance method, as in your case
```

further to that, it could also mean:

```
tree -> this.flattened(tree) //also doesn't apply to your case
```

From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13):

> If the compile-time declaration is an instance method, then the target
>   reference is the first formal parameter of the invocation method.
>   Otherwise, there is no target reference

Comment: please explain me more about that hidden this param?

Comment: This is a bit of an oversimplification, but for these purposes, `public Stream<Tree> flattened()` is basically the same thing as `public static Stream<Tree> flattened(Tree this)`.

Comment: In fact, I see you are already using it in your method: `Stream.of(this)`.

Comment: @JoeC your answer is kind of correct, but the way you phrase it and your last comment make me wonder whether this is the best way to explain it.

Comment: does every function<T,R> provide this hidden implementation?

Comment: @Joey there's no "hidden implementation". It is just syntactic sugar. The compiler is able to infer the type of the lambda you're writing because `Tree::flattened` contains all the context you need to build a lambda that takes a `Tree` and returns a `Stream<Tree>`. If your method was taking even just one parameter you would not be able to write this

Comment: @JoeC it's actually pretty hard to explain because it's "intuitive". I think the best answer would be a combination of the intuitive explanation and a quote from JLS

Comment: I would put it this way: `Tree::flattened` is equivalent to `tree -> tree.flattened()` when `flattened()` is an instance method.

Comment: I've added a small bit of the JLS and +1ed :)

Comment: thumbs up, i get it now

Comment: Actually don't think the JLS quote is enough on its own

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking back to the days of my compiler course.  In hindsight, a bit too low-level for this particular questioner.